# Computing the codifferential of $fdx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and consider the codifferential $$d^* :\Omega^p(U) \to \Omega^{n-p}(U)$$ given by $$d^*(\omega)=(-1)^{np+n-1} *\circ d \circ *(\omega).$$ Show that $$d^*(fdx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p) = \sum_{j=1}^p(-1)^j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge\widehat{dx_j} \wedge \dots\wedge dx_p.$$

Trying to compute this I got the following: $$\begin{align*} d^*(fdx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p)&= (-1)^{np+n-1} *\circ d \circ *(fdx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p) \\ &=  (-1)^{np+n-1} *\circ d(f dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{n})  \\
&= (-1)^{np+n-1} *\left( \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j \right) \wedge  dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n\right) \end{align*}$$

here is where I'm stuck. Is it so that all the terms with $j=p+1, ... n$ will vanish and I'm left with $$\left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j \right) \wedge  dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n = \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j$$ and then $$*\left(\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} *(dx_j) = \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge\widehat{dx_j} \wedge \dots\wedge dx_p?$$ This would result in $$d^*(fdx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p) = (-1)^{np+n-1}\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge\widehat{dx_j} \wedge \dots\wedge dx_p$$ which is not yet what we want. Could someone help me with where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs here:

$$\left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j \right) \wedge  dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n = \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j.$$

Note that the left hand side is a $(n - p + 1)$-form, and the right hand side is a one-form. Instead, you have

$$\left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j \right) \wedge  dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n = \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n.$$

---

From the discussion below, it seems that the OP knows how to complete the problem. With this in mind, here is the rest of the computation.

We have

\begin{align*}
d^*(fdx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p) &= (-1)^{np+n-1}\ast\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx^j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\right)\\
&= (-1)^{np+n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n).
\end{align*}

Since $\alpha\wedge\ast\beta = \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, and $\{dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_p} \mid 1\leq i_1 < \dots < i_p \leq n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $p$-forms, it follows that $\ast(dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_p}) = \operatorname{sign}(\sigma)dx_{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{j_{n-p}}$ where $\{j_1, \dots, j_{n-p}\} = \{1, \dots, n\}\setminus\{i_1, \dots, i_p\}$ with $j_1 < \dots < j_{n-p}$ and $\sigma \in S_n$ is the permutation with

$$\sigma(k) = \begin{cases}
i_k & 1 \leq k \leq p\\
j_k & p + 1 \leq k \leq n.
\end{cases}$$

In particular, $\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n) = \operatorname{sign}(\sigma)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p$. Instead of computing $\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)$ directly, we can calculate it implicitly as follows. Since

\begin{align*}
dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n &= dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\wedge\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n)\\
&= dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\wedge\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p\\
&= (-1)^{n-p+j-1}\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\wedge dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p\\
&= (-1)^{n-p+j-1}(-1)^{(n-p)p}\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^p\wedge dx^{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\\
&= (-1)^{n-p+j-1+(n-p)p}\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n,
\end{align*}

we have $\operatorname{sign}(\sigma) = (-1)^{n-p+j-1 + (n-p)p} = (-1)^{n - p + j - 1 + np - p^2} = (-1)^{np + n - 1 + j}$. Therefore

$$\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n) = (-1)^{np+n-1+j}dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx_j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p.$$

So we finally obtain

\begin{align*}
d^*(fdx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n) &= (-1)^{np+n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n)\\
&= (-1)^{np+n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(-1)^{np+n-1+j}dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx_j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n.
\end{align*}

Comment: We would have that $$\begin{align*}d^*(fdx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p) &= (-1)^{np+n+1}*\left( \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j \right) \wedge  dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n\right) \\ &=(-1)^{np+n+1}\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} *( dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n)\end{align*}$$

but what will become of this $*( dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n)$? Is it just $\widehat{dx_j} \wedge dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p$? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: You should write $dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx_j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p$ instead (note that $\widehat{dx_j}$ is not a one-form you're wedging with, but rather it is notation for excluding a term that would otherwise be there). With that in mind, you are correct, up to sign. To work out the sign, note that we must have $$dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\wedge\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n) = dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n.$$

Comment: It'll likely be $(-1)^j$, but how do we get rid of the first $(-1)^{np+n+1}$ term? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: It isn't $(-1)^j$. You can figure out the sign from my last comment.

Comment: I think it should have something to do with transpositioning $dx_j$, but I don't see how many times. @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: I mean that the lhs of $$dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\wedge\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n) = dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$$ doesn't even contain $dx_1$ right? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: It does, because $\ast(dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n) = (-1)^k dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx_j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p$ for some $k$ that needs to be determined. We can find $k$ by using the fact that $$dx_j\wedge dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\wedge (-1)^k dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{j-1}\wedge dx_{j+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_p = dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n.$$

Comment: Okay so we first move $dx_j$ between $dx_{j-1}$ and $dx_{j+1}$ and we pick up a sign $(-1)^{n-(p+1) + j}$ as it takes $n-p-1 + j$ transpositions. We then have $$dx_{p+1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n \wedge (-1)^k dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_j \wedge \dots \wedge dx_p.$$ Now we need to move this whole lhs up to $dx_n$ to the back of the expression, but it's a bit confusing to keep up with how many terms here are. @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: As you move $dx_1$ to the other side of $dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, you pick up a factor of $(-1)^{n-p}$. Likewise, as you move $dx_2$ to the other side of $dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, you pick up another factor of $(-1)^{n-p}$. Doing this for all the one-forms to the right of $dx_{p+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, you get the factor $(-1)^{n-p}$ a total of $p$ times, i.e. $((-1)^{n-p})^p = (-1)^{(n-p)p}$. In general, if $\alpha$ is a $p$-form and $\beta$ is a $q$-form, then $\alpha\wedge\beta = (-1)^{pq}\beta\wedge\alpha$.